# SELECT the parent of a record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this requirement that I need to attach a new column in select statement. It holds the disp_order of the parent level.

I currently have this sql statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_no, 
                code, 
                disp_order, 
                lvl, 
                description 
           FROM tbl_pattern

+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          | 1   | HK140904-1A |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 1          | 2   | HK140904-1B |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 2          | 3   | HK140904-1B |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 3          | 4   | HK140904-1C |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 4          | 5   | HK140904-1D |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 5          | 2   | HK140904-1E |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 6          | 3   | HK140904-1E |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 7          | 3   | HK140904-1X |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 8          | 4   | HK140904-1E |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 9          | 5   | HK140904-1E |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

parent column does not exist on table, but I want to get the disp_order of the  level higher than the current record.

From the example table, the result should be like this:

```
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+
| order_no | code | disp_order | lvl | description | parent |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+
| RM001-01 | 1    | 0          | 1   | HK140904-1A |        |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 1          | 2   | HK140904-1B |    0   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 2          | 3   | HK140904-1B |    1   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 3          | 4   | HK140904-1C |    2   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 4          | 5   | HK140904-1D |    3   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 5          | 2   | HK140904-1E |    0   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 6          | 3   | HK140904-1E |    5   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 7          | 3   | HK140904-1X |    5   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 8          | 4   | HK140904-1E |    7   |
| RM001-01 | 1    | 9          | 5   | HK140904-1E |    8   |
+----------+------+------------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Data representation through hierarchy of sample provided:

```
1
  └2
    └3
      └4
        └5
  └2
    └3
    └3
      └4
        └5
```

Comment: Your data doesn't make a lot of sense. There is nothing that says disp_order 8 should have 6 as a parent, other than maybe it's description.

Comment: Why does #9 map to a parent of 7? It has a level of 5 and the previous level 4 row has a display order of 8 so shouldn't that row be its parent?

Comment: @gengencera your data representation should probably show disp_orders and not levels. The levels are represented visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query to find the most recent `disp_order` for the previous level:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebbd2/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_pattern ( order_no, code, disp_order, lvl, description ) AS
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 0, 1, 'HK140904-1A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 1, 2, 'HK140904-1B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 2, 3, 'HK140904-1B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 3, 4, 'HK140904-1C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 4, 5, 'HK140904-1D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 5, 2, 'HK140904-1E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 6, 3, 'HK140904-1E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 7, 3, 'HK140904-1X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 8, 4, 'HK140904-1E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RM001-01', 1, 9, 5, 'HK140904-1E' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ( SELECT MAX( disp_order )
         FROM   tbl_pattern p
         WHERE  p.order_no   = t.order_no
         AND    p.code       = t.code
         AND    p.lvl        = t.lvl - 1
         AND    p.disp_order < t.disp_order ) AS parent
FROM   tbl_pattern t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebbd2/13/0)**:

```
| ORDER_NO | CODE | DISP_ORDER | LVL | DESCRIPTION | PARENT |
|----------|------|------------|-----|-------------|--------|
| RM001-01 |    1 |          0 |   1 | HK140904-1A | (null) |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          1 |   2 | HK140904-1B |      0 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          2 |   3 | HK140904-1B |      1 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          3 |   4 | HK140904-1C |      2 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          4 |   5 | HK140904-1D |      3 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          5 |   2 | HK140904-1E |      0 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          6 |   3 | HK140904-1E |      5 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          7 |   3 | HK140904-1X |      5 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          8 |   4 | HK140904-1E |      7 |
| RM001-01 |    1 |          9 |   5 | HK140904-1E |      8 |
```

Comment: disp_order 8 & 9 should be under 6, you have it under 7. It is pretty obscure though. Data would make a lot more sense if 7 was 9 and 8 & 9 were 7 & 8.

Comment: @PeterPaff Updated so #8 maps to a parent of 6 not 7. However, I cannot see any logic why #9 should map to anything other than a parent of 8 (if it maps to #7 then it should have a level of 4 not 5). Will query the OP on their data.

Comment: I didn't even notice that, but you're right, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MT0 I have updated my sample data. Typographical error. Sorry

Comment: @gengencera Rolled back to my original solution which now matches your updated expected results.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks! Any ideas how can I achieve this at the same time also have the children attached to it, I tried to reverse the logic in this SQL but no luck.

Comment: @gengencera Please ask a new question - add all the necessary details to that question (table structure, sample data, expected output, etc) so that it is a stand-alone question and include a link back to this question so people can see what you are building on. I'll try and answer that question as trying to work out the requirements through comments here is not easy.

Comment: @MT0 I see. I have asked a question and will update it to link it here.Thank you. Btw, here is the link of the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773824/recursive-query-in-oracle-to-find-children-and-sibling

Answer (score 1):

Self join your data. Correct join condition is the most important part. Then only use row_number() to filter rows with greatest disp_order for rows were there is more than one match.

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61fe5b/1)</sup>**

```
select disp_order, lvl, description, parent
  from (
    select t1.*, t2.disp_order parent, 
           row_number() over (partition by t1.disp_order 
                              order by t2.disp_order desc) rn
      from tbl_pattern t1 
      left join tbl_pattern t2 on t2.lvl = t1.lvl - 1 and t2.disp_order < t1.disp_order)
  where rn = 1
  order by disp_order
```

Comment: disp_order 8 & 9 should be under 6, you have it under 7. It is pretty obscure though. Data would make a lot more sense if 7 was 9 and 8 & 9 were 7 & 8.